# proper instantiation & memory management in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocoa, memory-management, instantiation, cocos2d-x

I've been looking for documentation for cocos2d-x but it seems to be really really poor beyond the very basics. I understand that my own classes should inherit from `CCObject` to be able to use (originally cocoa's) `retain`/`release` mechanism, but I'm still confused about what happens when you `new` something. `init` is not called automatically. is it OK to call it from inside the constructor? does that alone guarantee that my object will start with a reference count of 1? what is `CC_SAFE_DELETE` and when should I use it? do `release` and `autorelease` work exactly like in cocoa? what about `CC_SYNTHESIZE`? I just need to see a **properly coded** class example (and it's instantiation/destruction) to understand what I'm supposed to do so as not to screw and leave memory leaks.
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will look to the code of CCObject class, you will see that in it's constructor reference count is set to 1 there. So, object creation with `new` is correct. Init is not called because CCObject class has no such a method. Usually I prefer to create objects using static constructor. Smth like

```
MyClass* MyClass::createInstance()
{
    MyClass* object = new MyClass();

    // you can create virtual init method
    // and call it here

    if( initWasSuccessful )
    {
        object->autorelease();
    }
    else
    {
        CC_SAFE_RELEASE_NULL(object);
    }
    return object;
}
```

About all macroses like CC_SAFE_DELETE - you can find them in the code of cocos2dx. This macros just check if object is NULL to prevent crash on trying to call release method.

Comment: thank you! You inspired me to make this macro: http://pastebin.com/WKKZ5EBN if you have any suggestions to improve it I can open another question about it. I hope someone else finds it useful too.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Morion is great, I'd just like to add a few useful links about this matter.

Here you can find the official memory management in Cocos2d-x page:
[Memory Management in Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Memory_Management_in_Cocos2d-x)

This forum page also contains some more details and clarifications about it:
[Memory deallocation in Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/678)

Enjoy coding!