# Fatal signal 11 code 1-Schedule-Cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have GameModeSimple class which inherits Layer class.This is what I wrote Into that class:

```
void GameModeSimple::scheduleBreaks()
{
    float dt = getBreakGenerateDeltaTime();
    layer->schedule(schedule_selector(GameModeSimple::generateBreaks), 3);
}


void GameModeSimple::generateBreaks(float dt)
{
    repetitionCount--;

    CCLOG("Name is %i", layer->getTag());
}
```

Into "generateBreaks" function,When remove "CCLOG" it works but when write that crashes.This is Stack trace:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/delos3gxx/delos3geur:4.1.2/JZO54K/I8552XXAMK2:user/r
elease-keys'
pid: 7737, tid: 7761, name: Thread-23546  >>> com.game.breaker <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 4687):     #00  pc 00162ebe  /data/data/com.game.breaker
/lib/libcocos2dcpp.so (GameModeSimple::generateBreaks(float)+17): Routine GameMo
deSimple::generateBreaks(float) at D:\GameFile\COCOS\breaker\proj.android/jni/..
/../Classes/GameModeSimple.cpp:29
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 4687):     #01  pc 003f0fbc  /data/data/com.game.breaker
/lib/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::TimerTargetSelector::trigger()+208): Routine coc
os2d::TimerTargetSelector::trigger() at D:\GameFile\COCOS\breaker\proj.android/j
ni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCScheduler.cpp:170
```

Comment: "CCLOG("Name is %i", layer->getTag());" works into "scheduleBreaks"

Comment: It solved.The problem was autorelease().Just read these:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709538/proper-instantiation-memory-management-in-cocos2d-x    http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Reference_Count_and_AutoReleasePool_in_Cocos2d-x